# JToken.ToString() removing curly braces

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I have the following `JToken`:

```
{
    "ID": "9dbefe3f5424d972e040007f010038f2"
}
```

But whenever I run `ToString()` on the `JToken` object to get the underlying JSON in string form, it returns:

```
\"ID\": \"9dbefe3f5424d972e040007f010038f2\"
```

Escaping the quotes is expected, but why is it removing the curly braces? It's valid JSON. And this only seems to happen in certain cases, as I'm able to successfully run `ToString()` and have the curly braces intact on other (more complex) `JTokens`.

Comment: 1) The escaping of the quotes is done by Visual Studio when it displays a string in the GUI.  To see the string without escaping, in the Immediate Window type `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(token.ToString())`.  2) What library are you using -- [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json)?  3) Can you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem?

Comment: Can't reproduce.  In the Immediate Window, typing `Debug.WriteLine(JObject.Parse("{\"ID\": \"9dbefe3f5424d972e040007f010038f2\"}").ToString())` gives me back `{
  "ID": "9dbefe3f5424d972e040007f010038f2"
}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ToString()` returns the JSON representation of the contents of the `JToken`.  `JToken` is an abstract class, so what JSON is returned depends on what kind of `JToken` it is (as well as what it contains).

Here is a short example that should illustrate the point:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        JObject jo = new JObject();
        jo.Add("ID", "9dbefe3f5424d972e040007f010038f2");

        // token is a JObject
        DumpToken(jo);

        // token is a JProperty (the first property of the JObject)
        DumpToken(jo.Properties().First());

        // token is a JValue (the value of the "ID" property in the JObject)
        DumpToken(jo["ID"]);  
    }

    private static void DumpToken(JToken token)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(token.GetType().Name);
        Console.WriteLine(token.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
JObject
{
  "ID": "9dbefe3f5424d972e040007f010038f2"
}

JProperty
"ID": "9dbefe3f5424d972e040007f010038f2"

JValue
9dbefe3f5424d972e040007f010038f2
```

So, I suspect that when you are getting a bare name-value pair from `ToString()` you have a reference to a `JProperty` in your code, not a `JObject`.  You should only expect to get complete (valid) JSON when you call `ToString()` on a `JObject` or a `JArray`.